# Implementing a Min Heap with an Array: Insert and Remove Min (with duplicates)

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, heap, min-heap

I'm trying to implement a Min Heap in Java, but I'm having issues with inserting and removing elements (inserting at the end, removing the root as min). It seems to work for the most part (I use a program to visually display the heap and have been printing out the new roots when min has been removed, things like that).

My problem is, for some reason the root won't switch with a new item when a new item is added, but I can't figure out why at all. Also, it seems this is only the problem when there are a lot of duplicates, the heap doesn't seem completely capable of staying in order (the parent is smaller than the children). For the most part, it does. Only occasionally it doesn't, and to me it seems random.

This is done with generics, and basically following most algorithms. Everything else I know for a fact works, it's definitely a problem with these two methods.

```
public void insert(T e)  {
    if (size == capacity)
        increaseSize(); //this works fine

    last = curr; //keeping track of the last index, for heapifying down/bubbling down when removing min
    int parent = curr/2;
    size++; //we added an element, so the size of our data set is larger


    heap[curr] = e; //put value at end of array

    //bubble up
    int temp = curr;

    while (temp > 1 && ((Comparable<T>) heap[temp]).compareTo(heap[parent]) < 0) { //if current element is less than the parent
        //integer division
        parent = temp/2;
        swap(temp, parent); //the swapping method should be correct, but I included it for clarification
        temp = parent; //just moves the index value to follow the element we added as it is bubbled up
    }

    curr++; //next element to be added will be after this one


}

public void swap(int a, int b){
    T temp = heap[a];
    heap[a] = heap[b];
    heap[b] = temp;
}


public T removeMin() {

    //root is always min
    T min = heap[1];

    //keep sure array not empty, or else size will go negative
    if (size > 0)
        size--;

    //put last element as root
    heap[1] = heap[last];
    heap[last] = null;

    //keep sure array not empty, or else last will not be an index
    if (last > 0)
        last--;

    //set for starting at root
    int right = 3;
    int left = 2;
    int curr = 1;
    int smaller = 0;

    //fix heap, heapify down
    while(left < size && right < size){ //we are in array bounds

        if (heap[left] != null && heap[right] != null){ //so no null pointer exceptions
            if (((Comparable<T>)heap[left]).compareTo(heap[right]) < 0) //left is smaller
                smaller = left;
            else if (((Comparable<T>)heap[left]).compareTo(heap[right]) > 0) //right is smaller
                smaller = right;
            else //they are equal
                smaller = left;
        }
        if (heap[left] == null || heap[right] == null)//one child is null
        {
            if (heap[left] == null && heap[right] == null)//both null, stop
                break;
            if (heap[left] == null)//right is not null
                smaller = right;
            else //left is not null
                smaller = left;
        }


        if (((Comparable<T>)heap[curr]).compareTo(heap[smaller]) > 0)//compare smaller or only child
        {
            swap(curr,smaller); //swap with child
            curr = smaller; //so loop can check new children for new placement
        }
        else //if in order, stop
            break;

        right = 2*curr + 1; //set new children
        left = 2*curr;
    }


    return min; //return root
}
```

Any variables not declared in the methods are global, and I know a couple of things are probably redundant, like the whole current/last/temp situation in add, so I'm sorry about that. I tried to make all names self explanatory and explain all the checks I did in removeMin. Any help would be insanely appreciated, I've gotten as far as I can looking things up and debugging. I think I'm just fundamentally missing something here.

Comment: Are you using an IDE so that you can debug your code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using eclipse, so I can debug. I also have been using GraphViz to display the heap as a tree-like structure. I'm honestly not the best at using debuggers and usually have more luck with print statements, so I might be missing things due to that ineptitude.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you debug, you should simplify the code. There is something strange going on with 'last' variable. Also in 'insert' when you do the loop, probably temp should go to 0, that is

```
while (temp >= 0 &&......
```